# mkdir issue in bash script

Tags: bash, mkdir

I am trying to create a folder tree using the mkdir command, which is supposed to have the following structure:

```
rootfs
├── Fol1
│   ├── Fol11
│   └── Fol12
└── Fol2
```

I sucessfully created this tree using

```
mkdir -p /rootfs/{Fol1/{Fol11,Fol12},Fol2}
```

However the folder rootfs is supposed to be variable, which is why I tried

```
ROOT=/rootfs
FOLDERTREE=/{Fol1/{Fol11,Fol12},Fol2}
mkdir -p "$ROOT$FILETREE"
```

Although `echo "$ROOT$FILETREE"` yields exactly `/rootfs/{Fol1/{Fol11,Fol12},Fol2}` I do get a wrong filetree

```
rootfs
└── {Fol1
    └── {Fol11,Fol12},Fol2}
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Braces are not processed in the result of variable substitution. Use:

```
mkdir -p "$ROOT"/{Fol1/{Fol11,Fol12},Fol2}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use BASH array to keep all the directory paths as:

```
dirs=( "${ROOT}"/{Fol1/{Fol11,Fol12},Fol2} )
```

Then create it as:

```
mkdir -p "${dirs[@]}"
```